# Why can't I change background image of my HTML site?

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have developed a simple ASP.NET website; I have written a simple CSS to show a background image for that, but when I want to change the background image, the website shows the same image; did the ASP.NET cache the image?
The background image is `banner.jpg` and shows a picture, but I want to change that picture and another file replaces `banner.jpg`; the website shows the last picture.

Comment: ASP.NET doesn't cache your image, but your browser could. Clear your browser cache, or try different browsers. If that doesn't work, you should show us some code so we can see what you could've done wrong.

Comment: @AlanFluka please wait to test that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sounds like an unwanted image cache. do a hard refresh after replacing the image file by pressing ctrl + F5 and it should pull from the replaced image file